# Rounded Button Corners in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm developing an application in Firemonkey for Windows and OSX.  With the new Windows 11, I can see, by default in my application, that the form corners are rounded.  I've found code to call a Windows API for rounding corners but it requires passing an HWND parameter. Since I don't believe Firemonkey supports Windows handles, how do I go about rounding the corners on button and other controls to match the new Windows 11 look when the application is being built for Windows? (I'm using the Alexandria build of Delphi and I know enough to wrap the code with compile directives for Windows vs OSX.)

Comment: The rounded corners are handled by the OS itself, not by FMX. And yes, FMX UI controls typically do not use native `HWND`s, they are owner-drawn by FMX within the `TForm`'s native `HWND`. Although, a few select FMX controls now have a `ControlType` property in modern Delphi versions, which you can set to `Platform`, then they will use native `HWND`s. Getting the `TForm`'s `HWND` is easy (`FMX.Platform.Win.FormToHWND()`), but I have no idea how to access the `HWND`s of "native" controls (without resorting to Win32 APIs to hunt for them).

Comment: You could use Effects to mimic rounded corners for any FMX control

Comment: SilverWarior - I've never used Effects before.  Which of the many options should I look at?

Comment: @SilverWarior Could you post an answer for the Effects method please?